# I get a broken image icon for the output

Tags: php, html

I know it's accessing the directory because the correct number of broken icons are there. Even `alt='Image not there'` doesn't work, it only widens the element its in but doesn't show any text. I tried other scripts where it displayed the `alt='Image not there'` but still gave a broken image icon. I also tried to simply echo an image from the folder and still got a broken image icon so what am I doing wrong? Is it even a script thing or what is going on?

```
 <?php
 $dirname = "C:/uploads/";
 $images = scandir($dirname);
 shuffle($images);
 $ignore = Array(".", "..");
 foreach ($images as $curimg) {
     if (!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
         echo "<li><a href='".$dirname.$curimg."'>
         <img src='img.php?src=".$dirname.$curimg."&w=300&zc=1' alt='Image not working' /></a></li>\n ";
      }
 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: try using a relative path to display image directory/files

Answer (score 0):

You should provide an URL and not a local path here:

```
   echo "<li><a href='".$dirname.$curimg."'>

   <img src='img.php?src=".$dirname.$curimg."&w=300&zc=1' alt='Image not working' /></a>
```

`$dirname` is not accessable to the outside world and should be something like:

www.my.domain.com/uploads/

Comment: The fact that he's getting correct number of broken icons, shows that the path is being accessed correctly.

Comment: The SCRIPT can read the directory. The USER cannot: You provide an URL to image files / links. You proived server paths to the script. Web-programming 101..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a folder into your (if you are working in local machine)**local server** site folder. Because **PHP is a server side scripting language.** So only the files move into your folder correctly. then you can simply call

```
<?php
$dirname = "uploads/";
    $images = scandir($dirname);
    shuffle($images);
    $ignore = Array(".", "..");
    foreach($images as $curimg){

        if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
echo "<li><a href='".$dirname.$curimg."'>
<img src='img.php?src=".$dirname.$curimg."&w=300&zc=1' alt='Image not working' /></a></li>\n ";
            }
        } 
?>
```

if you call images from local machine its not a logic. because you are building website. this website not show only your system. it shows all system. also all systems are not contain a uploads folder.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem, makes sense too.